# Una consulta: [PHP - MySQLI]

Tags: php

Estimados

Quiero saber, debo agregar un registro por POST.

por ejemplo

```
if($_POST==add){
 $id= $_POST['id'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $userID = $_POST['userID'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table('id', 'name', 'userID') VALUES (NULL, "Jorge", "NULL o $userID");

}
```

Comment: Que error te genera ese código??

Comment: parece que debes agregar mas información, sobre tu problema

Comment: pense que un variable $userID puede agregar un valor porque tiene que userID es integer.

Comment: Las comillas deberían ser simples en lugar de dobles. Y deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de dinámicas.

Comment: Tienes errores en ese código, estas usando mal las comillas dobles, arregla eso, ademas la comparacion del if no tiene sentido, estas comparando todo el arreglo $_POST con add, incluso si fuera distinto te lanzaria un warning ya que add no esta definida como variable.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro id y userID son de integer pero pense agrega NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas,

En primer lugar, ¿Ese código tal cual es el que tienes desarrollado?

Hay varios errores de sintaxis que pueden hacer que no corra:

- la comparación del if `if($_POST==add){` add es una constante? en caso contrario, eso genera error. Si estás buscando el valor de un botón deberia ser algo como `if($_POST['nombrecampo']=='add')` .
- En el insert, si Jorge es un valor explicito, debe ir dentro de comillas, si lo que quieres es concatenar los valores del post, tendrias que hacer algo como :

  `$sql = "INSERT INTO table('id', 'name', 'userID') VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."', '".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['userID']."');`
  o

  `$sql = "INSERT INTO table('id', 'name', 'userID') VALUES ('$variable1',$variable2',$variable3');`

Ten en cuenta que el segundo caso es posible solo porque usas comillas dobles al crear el string, lo cual permite que se interpreten variables dentro de la cadena, esto hace, a nivel de rendimiento menos recomendable usar comillas dobles al crear cadenas pues hace que el motor de PHP necesite analizar la cadena completa para verificar si debe interpretar algún valor

Si es algo adicional, por favor explica un poco más tu pregunta.

Comment: podemos conversar por chat.

Comment: No estoy al tanto de que stack tenga chat, de igual manera plantea mejor tu duda si la respuesta no te es útil aun y vemos. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien cuál es tu problema pero la consulta debería ser sin las comillas en los nombres de las columnas:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(id, name, userID) VALUES (NULL, "Jorge", "NULL o $userID");
```

Si lo que quieres es cambiar tu consulta en función del valor de $userID, quedaría así:

```
$userID=NULL;
if(isset($_POST[$userID])){
    $userID=$_POST['userID'];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(id, name, userID) VALUES (NULL, 'Jorge', $userID)";
```

Comment: Tal y como está ahora el código, nunca se va a entrar en el `if` y $userID siempre será NULL. Creo que lo que quieres hacer es algo más como `if (isset($_POST['userID']))`

Comment: Cierto! No lo había revisado bien... Gracias!